# How to reuse an activity without creating a new one?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, stack, android-webview

I am new in android studio and working on a webview project. I want make chrome browser type function. When user browsing one url and if same time he want to go into 2nd url he just stop the current activity and go to home activity and open 2nd url. I want user can navigate between those activity like they can do it on chrome browser. Can anyone please give my some guidance how to make this project and how to navigate between opened url activity.Thanks.

Comment: you don't reuse an activity, the OS simply doesn't allow that. There is another component called `fragment` having similar capabilities that can have content being loaded in the background. you may like to check that out: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use only one Activity but use multiple fragments in the same activity. Give an add button like chrome. On clicking that create a new dynamic fragment and put the Webview inside the fragment. Put a cross button on opened fragment. On clicking the cross button destroy the fragment.

** Point is create and destroy fragments in the same activity.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please make it little more clear. I have a home activity where i have 12 button with different url and one detailed activity where i use web view. When user click on a button in home activity (Home page) i am starting detailed activity and using intent Extra to carry corresponding url. so my question is where to use fragment. in main activity or in detailed activity or use only one activity with fragment for hole app. i want when user click on new tab button the main layout or home page come into display like chrome. thanks again